# Context Menu works for child but not parent Widget

Tags: c++, qt

I'm developing a desktop program that displays data in several QWidget windows, and I'm attempting to use a context menu to allow the user to copy/save an image of the window for use elsewhere. I encounter a pretty strange error when trying to get the context menu to appear in the window. I initially used the Qt Design mode to create the `on_Plot_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)` slot for the entire window (entire Qwidget?), which did not work. When I create the `on_SignalPlot_customContextMenuRequested` slot, it works perfectly, but only on that specific widget, which is a subset of the entire window. I use identical code for each slot, and the debug output shows that the individual widget context menu request signal is emitted but the signal for the whole window is not. Is there a way to get it to work for the whole window?

Could the fact that the two child widgets take up the entire window cause the issue? I use a grid layout to ensure that the plots resize with the window.

(I'd show an image of the designer layout, but I don't have enough reputation.)

Does not work (code for whole window):

```
void Plot::on_Plot_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
    qDebug()<<"plot context menu requested";
    qDebug()<<pos;

    QMenu* menu=new QMenu();
    menu->addAction(copyWinAct);
    menu->addAction(saveWinAct);

    menu->exec(QCursor::pos());
}
```

Works Perfectly (code for individual plot/widget):

```
void Plot::on_SignalPlot_customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &pos)
{
    qDebug()<<"plot context menu requested";
    qDebug()<<pos;

    QMenu* menu=new QMenu();
    menu->addAction(copyWinAct);
    menu->addAction(saveWinAct);

    menu->exec(QCursor::pos());
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else has this problem, I've found a solution. By connecting the `customContextMenuRequested` signal to one slot, each sub-widget will display the same context menu. Setting the overall widget to the same slot will make the whole window behave in the same manner. I added the following code to the class default constructor and created the corresponding slot to get everything to behave properly.

```
this->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(this,SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)),this,SLOT(contextMenuSlot(QPoint)));

QList<QWidget *> windowChildren=this->findChildren<QWidget *>();

foreach (QWidget *child, windowChildren)
{
    child->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
    connect(child,SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)),this,SLOT(contextMenuSlot(QPoint)));
}
```

Good luck to anyone else fighting this problem.